# Accessing Threads on Remote Application Server

Tags: java, servlets, java-threads

I'm working on a legacy Java web application which runs on JBoss 6 EAP and is built using servlets.  The app is deployed on two separate web servers in the production environment, and the requests are load balanced.

The application has some data-intensive processes that are run in separate threads.  What I'm attempting to do is build a utility that will allow an administrative user to view information about the threads running on both instances of the app.  The only threads that will be shown are those invoked by the business logic.  As an example, a user on server A should be able to see the thread information for both server A and server B.

This is accomplished by server A invoking a servlet - ThreadMonitor - on servlet B which executes the following method.

```
public List<CustomProcess> getProcesses() {
  List<CustomProcess> allProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
  Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> allThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
  if (allThreads != null) {
    Iterator<Thread> threadIterator = allThreads.keySet().iterator();
    while(threadIterator.hasNext()) {
      Thread thread = iterator.next();
      if (thread instanceof CustomProcess) {
        allProcesses.add(thread);
      }
    }
  }
  return allProcesses;  
}
```

The issue is that when the servlet on server B executes this method, none of the threads started by the business logic running on server B are returned.  I've checked logs for security exceptions and see nothing that would indicate a problem.

Of course, the app on server B can call this method directly, and the threads that I'm expecting are returned.  The problem only occurs when this method is called by a servlet that is handling the HTTP request originating from server A.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: to better understand I/we need to know about the difference between "directly" and "from servlet" ... and my first intuition: are you sure that "servlet" and "app on server B" run in the "same jvm" ("same `java` process") ?

Comment: @xerx593 When I say "directly", I mean that when the front end hosted on server B is making the getProcesses() method call to get the threads on server B, the method returns the threads as expected.  However, when the front end on server A attempts to send a request to server B, the ThreadMonitor servlet on server B processes the request, calls the getProcesses() method, but nothing is returned.  I need to check on the JVMs.  I would think there is only one JVM on each server A and server B for this app, but your intuition now makes me question that.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this relates to what @xerx593 mentioned above in his comment.  It turns out that the infrastructure team has two JVMs set up on one application server.  The application is deployed to each JVM, and the threads to be monitored were running one of the JVMs while the servlet to which the request for a list of all threads was being sent was on another JVM.